# How to use if & else to find an answer in an array?

Tags: php, html, arrays, if-statement, conditional-statements

I am having a problem with simple PHP app where a user has to enter a correct answer from a list of available options. And that options are stored in an array. The problem is that i cannot use the options anytime in the script other than the array declaration point. I might sound dumb...and i am, believe me. Lets say this is the array:

```
$hobbyChoices = array("Movie","Music","Games","Books","Sports","Sleeping");
```

Now there is a text box in my script and `$_POST` method is used to submit the form. The correct choice which i have selected is 'Sports'. Now there are 4 possibilities a user might click submit, they are listed below.

1. A user clicks the submit button without entering any text in the textbox.
2. A user guesses the wrong choice which is from the `$hobbyChoices` but not 'Sports'.
3. A user guesses a choice which is not from the array. i.e anything other than what is in the array.
4. Finally, the user enters the correct choice that is 'Sports'.

This might seem pretty easy but the problem is that i cant use the names of the hobbies anywhere in the script, as mentioned before, other than the array declaration. Can i please get help? Also, when i tried to do one of the 4 possibilities, i encountered a problem with the uppercase and lowercase. This is seriously getting irritating, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: 1) Please show your attempts. Paste the code apart from just describing it. 2) Use a select box. That way the possibility of selecting an option that is not in the list is minimal (although you'll still need to check for it), as is the possibility to answer in the wrong case.

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding your question correctly, the following is what you are looking for:

```
<?php 
    $hobbyChoices = array("Movie","Music","Games","Books","Sports","Sleeping");

    if (isset($_POST['answer'])) {
        $answer = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['answer']);
        $correct_answer = $hobbyChoices[4];
        $response = "Your answer is not one of the answers listed!";

        foreach ($hobbyChoices as $value) {
            if (strtolower($answer) == strtolower($value) && (strtolower($answer) != strtolower($correct_answer))) {
                $response = "You selected the wrong answer from the list of options!";
            }
            else if (strtolower($answer) == strtolower($value) && (strtolower($answer) == strtolower($correct_answer))) {
                $response = "You have answered correctly!";
            }
        }

        print $response;
    }
?>

<form name="form" method="post">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>What is baseball?
            </td>
            <td><input type="text" name="answer" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" value="submit" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

strtolower is a function in php that converts strings to lowercase and would help you compare your two values.